# Chai 'expect' doesn't execute inside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, ramda.js

I'm writing unit-tests for my function that fetches info from some REST API. I am using `ramda` [`Future`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-fantasy/blob/master/docs/Future.md) type [(source)](https://github.com/ramda/ramda-fantasy/blob/master/src/Future.js).
The following test works weird:

```
  it('should return Maybe of Nothing', done => {

    let response = {
      status: 200,
      json: () => {
        return {
          results: []
        }
      }
    }

    let fakeFetch = {
      fetch: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve(response)
        })
      }
    }

    //                 String -> Future Error Maybe
    let result = Utils.fetchGiantBomb(faker.random.word(), fakeFetch.fetch); 

    result.fork(err => {
      assert.fail(err, 'expected to return Maybe of Nothing'); 
      done();
    }, data => {
      expect(Maybe.isJust(data)).to.be.true;
      done();
    })

  })
```

`data` should be of type `Maybe.Nothing`. If I expect  `Maybe.isNothing` the test passes, but I want to see what happens when the test fails, so I set it to `Maybe.isJust`, which return false. After looking at this for a while, I noticed that when the `expect` fail it jump up to the error handling (`err` callback), which then just stop executing any assertion (which result in a 2000ms timeout).

In the `Future` sources I saw that when the success callback fails, it executes the failure callback. How can I complete this test so it display that the data is not what I expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, when your REST call fails, `done()` is never called.

Not sure if `expect` has a .catch method when it fails, but you can try to add

```
.catch(done);
```

at the end of your expect function.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `future.fork(errorHandler, successHandler)` will currently ensure that any exceptions thrown in the `successHandler` will propagate through to the `errorHandler`.

One way around this (though perhaps not ideal as it is undocumented) is to call `future._fork(errorHandler, successHandler)` rather than `future.fork` where errors thrown in the `successHandler` will not be captured.

Alternatively, a number of test frameworks support passing an error to the `done` callback such as:

```
result.fork(err => {
  done('Expected to return Maybe of Nothing: ' + err);
}, data => {
  expect(Maybe.isJust(data)).to.be.true;
  done();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Ramda shouldn't catch the exception there. But i don't know what's they are trying to do.

It look like you are using Mocha. It maybe good idea to convert your Future to Promise first, then observe the Promise. ie:

```
const futureToPromise = future => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => future.fork(reject, resolve))
}

it('should return Maybe of Nothing', () => {

  let response = {
    status: 200,
    json: () => {
      return {
        results: []
      }
    }
  }

  let fakeFetch = {
    fetch: () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(response)
      })
    }
   }

  // String -> Future Error Maybe
  let result = Utils.fetchGiantBomb(faker.random.word(), fakeFetch.fetch); 
  // return it because Mocha can handle this
  return futureToPromise(result).then(data => {
    expect(Maybe.isJust(data)).to.be.true;
  }, () => {
    // fail
    assert.fail(err, 'expected to return Maybe of Nothing'); 
  })
})
```